# flutter how to open a specific directory using file_picker

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to open the application documents directory, where the app is going to store some files, but I can't get it to work. Using file_picker, I only can open the external storage, which isn't what I need. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you attempting to open the application documents directory? What are you using to identify the application documents directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flutter `path_provider` package to get the application documents directory

```
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()
    .then((directory) => myAppDocsDirectory = directory);
```

.. then use `file_picker` with `myAppDocsDirectrory`

Comment: I understand, I was using path provider too, but how would I go about using file_picker with the app docs directory?